# Writing a conditional remove duplicates statement in Excel based on values in other columns

Tags: excel, if-statement, duplicates

[image: sample data]I'm trying to remove/condense duplicate rows in a column based on values in other columns. What I'm trying to do is have Excel spot duplicates in Column A, then within that group of duplicates, delete those which don't contain a certain value (x) in Column B and C, and also condense redundant values in columns B and C into one row. However, if there are no records within a group of duplicates that contain value (x) in Column B or C, then delete all except one (see row 16/17 in Column A)

Edit: Attached is a sample of the raw data (left table), and what I'm trying to achieve through a statement (right table).

Any help on how to write a statement that could execute this task is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide sample data and show us the code, that you have so far?

Comment: Hi Qualia, just edited the question and added a picture of what I'm working with. Let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Have a look at my answer. Although I guess that it can also be done with the `FILTER` formula of **Office 365**.

Answer (score 0):

I would use **PowerQuery** to achieve this.

[image]

## Approach

1. Select `A1:B19`, go to **Data** tab in Ribbon and choose **From table/range** to open *PowerQuery* editor and load the selected region into a query. Rename it to "Load_Data".
2. Create the following additional queries:

[image]

### Unique_ColumnA

```
let
    Source = Load_Data,
    KeepColumnA = Table.SelectColumns(Source ,{"Column A"}),
    RemoveDuplicates = Table.Distinct(KeepColumnA)
in
    RemoveDuplicates
```

### Content_ColumnB_C

```
let
    Source = Load_Data,
    CheckIfEmpty = Table.AddColumn(Source, "IsEmpty", each if ([Column B] <> null) and ([Column C] <> null) then false else true),
    FilterForNonEmpty = Table.SelectRows(CheckIfEmpty, each ([IsEmpty] = false))
in
    FilterForNonEmpty
```

### Result

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(Unique_ColumnA, {"Column A"}, Content_ColumnB_C, {"Column A"}, "Content_ColumnB_C", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    Show_ColumnBC = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Content_ColumnB_C", {"Column B", "Column C"}, {"Column B", "Column C"})
in
    Show_ColumnBC
```

Comment: When I run the Content_ColumnB_C query (and plug in all the columns from my actual dataset (~8)) I receive only TRUE values, despite that there are numerous rows where all distinguished columns are null. Is this because I'm adding more than 2 columns in the each if statement?

Comment: let
    Source = Load_Data,
    CheckIfEmpty = Table.AddColumn(Source, "IsEmpty", each if ([MEMBER_RATING] <> null) and ([TAGS] <> null) and ([Tag 2] <> null) and ([CompanyAccount] <> null) and ([Title] <> null) and ([Street Address] <> null) and ([City] <> null) and ([State] <> null) and ([Zip] <> null) and ([Phone Number 1] <> null) and ([Phone Number 2] <> null) then false else true),
    FilterForNonEmpty = Table.SelectRows(CheckIfEmpty, each true)
in
    FilterForNonEmpty

Comment: The formula checks if *at least one column* is empty. In that case, it returns **TRUE**. It would only result in **FALSE** if *all columns are filled with values* or in other words, if *no column is null*. Hence, the name "IsEmpty".

Comment: Ah, I see. How would I structure a query that would essentially do the opposite of that? Basically only have **FALSE** if all indicated columns are _null_. I feel like this structure is more appropriate for the actual dataset that I'm working with.

Comment: Then replace each `<>` by `=`.